# Graph describing how does community respond to your activity

Tags: support, notifications, graphs

I was wondering at what ration and characteristic the community responds to the actions of the user. I have some rough estimation:

> [image: activity of user and the community]

Rough indeed. I'd be surely be able to create similar graphs (not visually I mean, but with same purpose) if I knew where to get the data. Can I fetch log of my activity and notifications with timestapms?

How could I filter it to get things like `questions`->`comments` or `comments`->`comments` (`you`->`community`). It'd be interesting to observe this among sites and specific times.

I suppose this would only work with a profile I have access to.

Is it possible to get notifications and activity data in reasonable format with timestamps? Can votes - `cast` or (logical) `received` - be included?

Comment: Available through the API...

Comment: I've actually done some googling already, so I've found that there **is** API. It wasn't so hard to find out. Isn't there anything else you could share on that matter?

Answer (score 4):

To get an start with an query that will roughly give you an history of events based on the public available data in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) check this [one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/521958?UserId=607407):

```sql
declare @uid int = ##userid:int?607407##

select creationdate
     , 'Posted ' + substring('QA',posttypeid,1) as event
     , id as [Post Link]
     , owneruserid as [User Link]
from posts
where owneruserid = @uid
union 
select p.creationdate
     , 'Received A'
     , p.id
     , p.owneruserid
from posts p
inner join posts oq on oq.id = p.parentid
where oq.owneruserid = @uid
union 
select c.creationdate 
     , 'Comment on ' + substring('QA',posttypeid,1)
     , postid
     , userid
from comments c
inner join posts p on p.id = c.postid
where p.owneruserid = @uid
union 
select c.creationdate
     , 'Comment after Comment'
     , c.postid
     , c.userid
from comments c
inner join comments oc on oc.postid = c.postid
where oc.userid = @uid
and c.creationdate > oc.creationdate
union 
select v.creationdate
     , 'Vote ' + vt.name
     , postid
     , v.userid
from votes v
inner join votetypes vt on v.votetypeid = vt.id
inner join posts p on p.id = v.postid
where p.owneruserid = @uid
union 
select ph.creationdate
     , pht.name
     , ph.postid
     , ph.userid
from posthistory ph
inner join posthistorytypes pht on pht.id = ph.posthistorytypeid
inner join posts p on p.id = ph.postid
where p.owneruserid = @uid
order by 1 desc
```

It is an union for all major events by a single user or on their posts. When run today the result looks like this:

[image: history of events of a single user]

I leave it to you to do the counting, grouping and graphing you want to do.